# Photo upload, Crop and Save using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

We are working on a social network project based on CI framework. I searched on the web but got confused. How to upload photo, allow user to crop the photo and save it using database so that it could be retrieved at the time of call? I'm using this for profile picture.

**On view:**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart ('index.php/Main/do_upload'); ?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('title'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image</td>
        <td><?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </tr>       
</table>
```

**On controller:**

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('Material_view', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far. Update your question with that. So that we shall provide you with the steps in order to improve your code.

Comment: first on view I created the form using php form then on controller I create the function do_upload(). I did it with the reference but it din't worked.

Comment: Why cant you provide with the code. if you provide so it will be useful for rectifying the error right.

Comment: @Aryan paste it in your question by clicking on the edit button

Answer (score 0):

Use Bluimp Multiple fileupload (https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload) and Croppr (https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) plugins together.
In Bluimp you can get enough code (there is a codeigniter class in their site) to handle file upload in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with cropper js. i have used this and it is very easy and it will full fill your requirement

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

Answer (score 0):

Create A Image model and paste the code

```
<?php 
class Image_model extends CI_Model {
 public function __construct()  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
}
public function do_resize($filename)
{

    $source_path =  'uploads/' . $filename;
    $target_path =  'uploads/thumb/thumb_'.$filename;

    $config_manip = array(

        'image_library' => 'gd2',
        'source_image' => $source_path,
        'new_image' => $target_path,
        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 150
    );
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config_manip);
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config_manip);


    if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        die();
    }
}

public function img_upload()
{
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => "uploads",
        'allowed_types' => "*",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "5048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        'max_height' => "3000",
        'max_width' => "3000"
    );
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $response   =    array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->do_resize($response['upload_data']['file_name']);

    }
    /*else{
        $error              =   array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
        //print_r($error);die(); 

    }*/
  }
}
```

Call this function like this in your controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Post extends CI_Controller {
   public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('image_model');
    }
   public function add() {
       if(isset($_FILES)){
             $config                =   $this->image_model->img_upload();
             $file_data             =   $this->upload->data();
             $data['feature_image'] =   $file_data['file_name'];
            }
   $lat_id      =       $this->your_model->save($data);
 }
```